# How do I set a plain text field value to be empty?

Tags: hooks

```
<?php
function MY_MODULE_node_update(NodeInterface $node)
{
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {

        $nid = $node->id();
        $nodeType = $node->getType();
    
        $vid = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                ->getStorage('node')
                ->getLatestRevisionId($nid);

        $comments = $node->get('field_workflow_comment')->getValue();

        foreach($comments as $comment){
            $revision_log = ($comment['value']);
        }

        // $empty = array();
        // $commentEmpty = $node->set('field_workflow_comment', $empty);
        
        $node->field_workflow_comment = [];

        $timestamp = REQUEST_TIME;

        $connection = Database::getConnection();

        $add_revision_log = $connection->update('node_revision')
                            ->fields([
                                'revision_log' => $revision_log
                            ])
                            ->condition('nid', $nid)
                            ->condition('vid', $vid)
                            ->condition('revision_timestamp', $timestamp)
                            ->execute(); 
        $node->save();
     
    }
}
```

This does not work for me on *hook_node_update()*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the field to an empty array:

```php
$node->field_name = [];
$node->save();
```

Comment: Hi Jaypan, but while I try to save this is the error message i get 

Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Update existing 'node' entity revision while changing the revision ID is not supported. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 815 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

how to solve this  ?

Comment: Can't tell, need to see more of your code.

Comment: Updated kindly check jaypan

Comment: You're trying to update the node, in a hook that is called when the node is updated. This will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks  Jaypan, Understood